# webview in RelativeLayout to use in DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I do not have much experience with screen layouts xml. I would like to show my screen like this:
http://www.consulta-rapida.com/layout.png

I did the xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNomeFavorito"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dip"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingBottom ="9dip"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />
        <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tvNomeFavorito2"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_marginLeft="75dip"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:paddingBottom ="9dip"
             android:text=""
             android:textColor="#040404"
             android:textSize="20dip"
             android:textStyle="bold"
             android:typeface="sans" />
</LinearLayout>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvNomeFavorito2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvNomeFavorito2"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

`

What did I do wrong? Where should I change to get of the form I need?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this. By just using a LinearLayout and setting the orientation to vertical, all of the child elements of the linearlayout will lay right on top of one another. Then you just set the `android:layout_weight` property to the webview to `"1"` so that the webview will take up all the extra space:

```
<LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNomeFavorito"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:typeface="sans" />
            <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tvNomeFavorito2"
                 android:text=""
                 android:textColor="#040404"
                 android:textSize="20dip"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:typeface="sans" />

            <WebView
                 android:id="@+id/webView1"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did not work! :(
the textview components were hidden. And the webview is not occupying the rest of the screen as I wanted.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the android:layout_width and android:layout_height values for each of the widgets so this should work now. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Awesome. I am glad I was able to help.